# What is the meaning of 知ってのことか？

Tags: grammar, translation, anime

[image]

This sentence is from "little witch academia" episode 10 first season. It looks like it's an abbreviated form of something. What is it? The character is clearly asking if one understands what he is saying but I don't get the nuance of `動詞て形＋のことか`.

My take is that the construction is emphasizing the expression as in このいいプレゼントを買ったのはあなたを思ってのことだ。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already understand あなたを思ってのことだ, then there is no difference. 知ってのことか by itself is an abbreviation of nothing, but the "result part" is in the previous context.

- [N1文法　～は～てのこと](https://blognihongo.com/n1/grammar_ha_tenokoto/)
- [〜は〜てのこと｜日本語能力試験　JLPTにない文型](https://www.edewakaru.com/archives/14241881.html)

> このプレゼントを買ったのはあなたを思ってのことだ。
> I bought this gift because I was thinking of you.
>
> (お前が魔女を屋敷に入れたのは)私が魔女を毛嫌いしておると知ってのことか？
> *(Did you let the witches into the mansion)* knowing I hate witches?

Hanbridge's statement sounds sarcastic, like "You did this on purpose to annoy me?"

Comment: Thank you. I just wanted to confirm if my interpretation was correct.